# How to give different images to grid view items without having to create different templates?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am adding items to a grid view on the click of a button and i want different items to have different images. There are 6 items and i dont want to create 6 different templates. Is there any way that i can  do this with a single template? below is a code snippet of my data template :

```
<StackPanel>


                <!-- Shadow -->
                <Image Source="{Binding Time, Converter={StaticResource ThemeImageConverterClockShadow}}" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="10"
                    Canvas.Top="25"/>



                <!-- Face -->
                <Image Source="{Binding Time, Converter={StaticResource FaceBackground}}" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="10"
                    Canvas.Top="10" />
<StackPanel/>
```

I want to change only the shadow image for each item. I tried binding a property and returning a different image based upon the no. of grid view items present. But the image changes for all the grid view items whenever a new item is added to the gridview

Update:
Gridview if it helps

```
<GridView              


         x:Name="ThemeGridView"                    
                ItemsSource="{Binding Clocks}" 
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WorldClockTemplate}"
                SelectionChanged="Clock_SelectionChanged"              
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle1}">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>

        </GridView>
```

Comment: Could you please show the actual `GridView` markup? The version where you attempt to bind the image to a property. Also how to you add the items to the `GridView` on the button click? Can you not set the image on the new item when you create it? Why are you using the number of items currently present in the grid to determine the image?

Comment: Its a world clock actually, user can add clock of his desired location on the click of a button in appbar. I am just looking to give different shadow effects to different clocks. The user can add max 6clocks, so i was just looking to change the shadow image based on the number of clocks that are already present on the screen.

Comment: The reason I wanted to see how you did the binding to the property is that it should work. If you add an `ImageSource` property to your data item and bind to it in the template of the column, then you should get the desired effect by setting different images when creating the data items when you add items to the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what's going on with your code. I'm guessing that you are using the `GridView` item count in your converter `ThemeImageConverterClockShadow` to select the appropriate image. Whenever a new item is added to the `GridView` all the bindings will most likely be reevaluated, which explains why you get the same image for all the rows. What you should be doing instead is to have a property on your data item which indicates which shadow image to use, and the value should be set when you add a new item to the `ItemsSource`.

One alternative would be:

```
<StackPanel>
    <!-- Shadow -->
    <Image Source="{Binding ShadowImage}" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="10"
                Canvas.Top="25"/>

    <!-- Face -->
    <Image Source="{Binding Time, Converter={StaticResource FaceBackground}}" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="10"
                Canvas.Top="10" />
<StackPanel/>
```

where you have a property `ImageSource ShadowImage` on your data item in the `ItemsSource`:

```
public class MyDataItem 
{
    ....
    public ... Time { get { ... } set { ... } }
    public ImageSource ShadowImage { get { ... } set { ... } }
}
```

You then set the image when you create the data item in the code which adds a row to the `GridView`. Alternatively, you could add some `ShadowType` property instead, and then still use the converter but bind to the entire data item and then use both the `Time` and `ShadowType` to select the image:

```
<StackPanel>
    <!-- Shadow -->
    <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ThemeImageConverterClockShadow}}" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="10"
                Canvas.Top="25"/>

    <!-- Face -->
    <Image Source="{Binding Time, Converter={StaticResource FaceBackground}}" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="10"
                Canvas.Top="10" />
<StackPanel/>
```

with a Converter along the lines of:

```
public class ThemeImageConverterClockShadow : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dataItem = value as MyDataItem;
        if (dataItem != null)
        {
           // Use dataItem.Time and dataItem.ShadowType to select an image
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya thats whatz happening! But i didnt get your solution! If its not too much effort can you give a sample code snippet?